# After setting Custom Block from controller the Content output comes above Header

Tags: magento-1.9

```
public function ShowproductAction()
    {

        $product_result = Mage::getModel('helpmebuy/helpmebuyoptions')->getproduct();
        $allproduct_result = Mage::getModel('helpmebuy/helpmebuyoptions')->getallproduct();
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        $session->setData('mproduct', $product_result);
        $session->setData('rproduct', $allproduct_result);
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');
        $block->setTemplate('helpmebuy/finalpage.phtml');

        echo $block->toHtml();
        $this->IndexAction();


}
```

I am using above code to set template form controller action, but the output comes before the header . How do i fix this

My second concern is how do i pass these data to that template rather than setting them in session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this in your `indexAction` for showing block in content area

```
$this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');
        $block->setTemplate('helpmebuy/finalpage.phtml');

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

    $this->renderLayout();
```

for for passing the you use `Mage::register()` because session need to reload the page

```
 public function ShowproductAction()
{

    $product_result = Mage::getModel('helpmebuy/helpmebuyoptions')->getproduct();
    $allproduct_result = Mage::getModel('helpmebuy/helpmebuyoptions')->getallproduct();

    Mage::register('mproduct', $product_result);
    Mage::register('rproduct', $allproduct_result);



  }
```

for getting the value in template

```
$var = Mage::registry('mproduct');
 $var1 = Mage::registry('rproduct');
```

Answer (score 1):

Echoing in a controller is a wrong approach. You should add block to layout.

Comment: How do i pass that data to my block or redirect to template then when i have that data ? what is the magento way ?

Comment: You are already adding data to session. You can fetch it in your block class.

Comment: But if  i remove echo $block->toHtml(); from controller i dont  get any output

Comment: Basically my question is i have data in my sessions ,  how redirect to that block from controller

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly,  welcome back. good to see you Again

Comment: @AmitBera Can you please point me in the right way

Comment: did you  using ajax for getting data  from controller?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that,**you have using Ajax  for getting data from  the controller's ShowproductAction()**.

first,you need to **load layout using**  `$this->loadLayout()`; before call of layout using `$this->getLayout()`.

Instead of **echo** use `$this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());` for **rendered content  of blocks**.

**Note that**  `$this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());`  add  this code just before end of function `ShowproductAction`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Magento approach

1) Define your block and template in layout configuration file

2) Use controller for the following action

a) `$this->loadLayout()`

b) Set your data to registery in your case

```
$product_result = Mage::getModel('helpmebuy/helpmebuyoptions')->getproduct();
$allproduct_result = Mage::getModel('helpmebuy/helpmebuyoptions')->getallproduct();

Mage::register('mproduct', $product_result);
Mage::register('rproduct', $allproduct_result);
```

c) Render Layout using  `$this->renderLayout()`

3) Create Block Which you have define in your layout configuration

4) Create Public method in your Block for retrieve and return your data like below

a) `public function getMproduct() {
           return Mage::registry('mproduct');      }`
   b) Same for other registery data

5) Create .phtml file to the specified location in Layout Configration
6) Access and print block method something like `$this->getMproduct()`

Let me know if you have doubts.

Comment: Please note code is not tested there might be some syntax erros.